# difference between "Code Injection" and "Process Injection"?

Tags: code-injection

what's difference  between  `Code injection` and `process injection`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Code injection is the introduction of executable information into the regular processing of a program, typical example is SQL injection. Process injection is when the introduction of the extraneous executable is done at the process level, in memory where the process runs. The latter can also be done through the use of dll hooks.